# Create a blurb from text from a database (similar to "read more")

Tags: php, zend-filter-strip-tags

I am trying to cut text from a database off if `<!-- break -->` is found then only show what is before the break. I currently have this code

```
        //get the description before the more link
        $project_blurb =  htmlspecialchars_decode($project_data['p_desc']);
        if (strstr($project_blurb, '<!-- break -->')) {
            $project_blurb = explode("<!-- break -->" , $project_blurb);
            $project_desc = $project_blurb[0];
            }
        else{
            $project_desc = $project_blurb;
        }
```

This works except that the text starts with a `<p>` tag and currently I'm cutting it off the ending `</p>` tag which is breaking the html on the site. I want to know if there is a better way to only get the description before the "break".  I've tried to us strip_tags but this also strips the comment that I need to search for and creates some ugly formatting.

Thanks

Comment: Could you not get the text before <!-- break --> comment and THEN use strip_tags? I don't see an easy way around this problem, you'll have to write a script which closes open tags, there doesn't seem to be an easier way. Or you could strip the tags and format the raw text yourself.

Comment: Sbm007 I mean I could just do strip_tags then limit it to a specific amount of characters sure. Using the `<!-- break -->` allows the user to decide where to end the description. Another way to do it would be to add a new field in the database and store the blurb in there.

Comment: he's saying to split the text by the comment first, and then use strip_tags on it only after you have the first blurb. Also, why do you have a `<p>` tag surrounding the entire text? That sounds like it should be part of the page which the text is inserted into, rather than the text itself.

Comment: I guess that is one way of doing it. It just doesn't look as pretty if they have two paragraphs before the split. Also I'm using tinymce to format the data before it's inserted into the database that that's why it's inserting the `<p>` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to select up to your break, call strip tags after you get the field.  Also, you can make it a little more efficient by only searching for your break once:

```
<?
$project_blurb = htmlspecialchars_decode($project_data['p_desc']);
if (($pos = strpos('<!-- break -->'), $project_blurb) >= 0) {
  $project_desc = substr(0, $pos);
} else {
  $project_desc = $project_blurb;
}
$project_desc = strip_tags($project_desc);
?>
```

Instead of putting a special comment in your text, consider defining a maximum length for your description, so you don't have to search the string.  This will be much more efficient and won't require you to modify your input.

If you are going to link to the full-text from your page, instead of expanding it in place, you could also consider letting your database do some of the work for you.  Assuming you are using MySQL, you could use `LEFT(p_desc, 200)` to pull only the first 200 characters of the database from the p_desc field.

Comment: Thanks for your help, however when I execute the code I get an `syntax error, unexpected ','` I believe this is because of the parenthesis around the `<!--break -->` of `strpos('<!-- break -->'), $project_blurb) >= 0)` I'm not an expert but shouldn't it be `$pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);` meaning the `$project_blurb` should be first. I'm a beginner so I'm still trying to figure all this out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A solution I came up with is similar to jheddings method.

I corrected his script up and used a code snippet I found here

[Snipplr Close Tags In A HTML Snippet](http://snipplr.com/view.php?codeview&id=3618)

To find open tags and close them (Note that I am assuming you really only care about closing p tags)

> Note: The snippet may have shortcomings but it managed to get the job done for the example I was working with

So in the example script below I am taking the sample blurb cutting out everything after the break marker and appending "..." to it. Then we strip_tag everything except the p tags. Then I am using the closetags function to match all tags and close any that are unmatched.

It is far from neat but if your data set is simple enough it may be a quick way to go about it.

```
<?php
$project_blurb = "<p>This is a blurb with content</p><p>This is another<!-- break -->blurb</p>"; 

if ($pos = strpos($project_blurb, '<!-- break -->')) {
    $project_desc = substr($project_blurb, 0, $pos)."...";
} else {
    $project_desc = $project_blurb;
}

$project_desc = strip_tags($project_desc, '<p>');
$project_desc = closetags($project_desc);

echo $project_desc;

function closetags ( $html )
{
    #put all opened tags into an array
    preg_match_all ( "#<([a-z]+)( .*)?(?!/)>#iU", $html, $result );
    $openedtags = $result[1];

    #put all closed tags into an array
    preg_match_all ( "#</([a-z]+)>#iU", $html, $result );
    $closedtags = $result[1];
    $len_opened = count ( $openedtags );
    # all tags are closed
    if( count ( $closedtags ) == $len_opened )
    {
        return $html;
    }
    $openedtags = array_reverse ( $openedtags );
    # close tags
    for( $i = 0; $i < $len_opened; $i++ )
    {
        if ( !in_array ( $openedtags[$i], $closedtags ) )
        {
            $html .= "</" . $openedtags[$i] . ">";
        }
        else
        {
            unset ( $closedtags[array_search ( $openedtags[$i], $closedtags)] );
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You guys are all doing it wrong!!

It's coming fromt he DB so this is how **i** do it:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(description, 1, INSTR(description, '<!-- break -->') -1);
```

Why make it overtly difficult w/ programming languages???

Demo!!

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo (description text);
INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('This is a really long paragraph. <!-- break --> OK, not really ;-)');
SELECT SUBSTRING(description, 1, INSTR(description, '<!-- break -->') - 1) AS description FROM foo;
// Output: This is a really long paragraph.
```